# htaccess mod-rewrite to take website offline

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following htaccess code that helps me take my website offline to all users with the exception of REMOTE_ADDR. This works well for me. However, i've currently added an exception for the websiteOffline.php file which is the file that is displayed while the website is offline.

I want to add exception for two folders "images" and "styles"

any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/styles/websiteOffline.php
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.54$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)  /parents/styles/websiteOffline.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done without `mod_rewrite`, too:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /parents/styles/websiteOffline.php

<FilesMatch "websiteOffline\.php|\.(css|js|png|gif|jpe?g)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from All
</FilesMatch>

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 192.168.1.54
Deny from All
```

Comment: The only thing that might need to consider using this method is that if the site is crawled during this time it won't show the proper `302 Moved Temporarily` which could mess up the SEO if that is a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/styles/websiteOffline.php
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.54$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/yourimage.jpeg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/styles/yourstyle.css
RewriteRule  ^(.*)  /parents/styles/websiteOffline.php [L]
```

if you only have to access some files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see how it works for you. This should allow you to use both `styles` and `images` directories without specifying image or css file name in the rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.54$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/styles/(websiteOffline\.php|(.+)\.css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/(.+)\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)  /parents/styles/websiteOffline.php [R=302,L]
```